# Passing variables to the library function

Tags: r, load

```
package <- c("car","ggplot2","pastecs","psych")
for (i in package){
  if (!(i %in% rownames(installed.packages()))){
    install.packages(i)
  } else{
     print(paste(i,"has been installed"))
     library(i)
     }
 }
```

I wrote a loop to see whether the package is installed, and if it is available, the library should load it.

```
However I got an error: there is no package called 'i'
```

Why can't I pass the value in variable `i` to the `library` function ?

Comment: Try `library(i, character.only = T)`

Comment: By default, `library(i)` looks for package with name "i". I believe this is made for convenience purposes in order to save typing quotes around package name. Override this behaviour as @csgillespie hints, there's also an example of that in `?library`.

Comment: Thanks for character.only !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simpler version of your code (incorporating @csgillespie's suggestion):

```
p <- c("car","ggplot2","pastecs","psych") 
for(i in seq_along(p)) {
    if(!require(p[i], character.only=TRUE)) {
        install.packages(p[i])
        library(p[i], character.only=TRUE)
    }
}
```

Note that your code does not work because of non-standard evaluation in `library` and `require`. The `character.only` argument resolves this (per documentation `? library`):

> character.only
>   a logical indicating whether package or help can be assumed to be character strings.

Comment: Side question: what is the purpose of looping over the index? I thought the overhead is only substantial on long vectors, am I incorrect?

Comment: @tonytonov Stylistic mainly.