# When shouldn't I explicitly call functions?

Tags: r

See the helper:

```
library = function(name) {
    
    # check if package is installed. if not, do it.
    if (!name %in% installed.packages()) {
        install.packages(name)
        }
        
    # load package silently
    suppressPackageStartupMessages(base::library(name))
}
```

To avoid namespace issues, I've explicitly called `base::library()`, which gives me `Error in base::library(name): there is no package called ‘name’` when I call any package. If I don't use `base::`, it works just fine. Question is, why did it not work?

Comment: I get the same error regardless of whether I qualify with the namespace, on R 4.0.5. Not familiar enough to give an actual explanation of what's going on, but a workaround is to use the `character.only = TRUE` argument when calling library inside a function like that.

Comment: `library` tries really hard (using `substitute(.)`) to be convenient and not require quotes around package names. @IceCreamToucan's suggestion is the only way to use `library` programmatically. (Well, there are ways around it, but they are typically not worth it.) Non-standard evaluation (NSE) can be really tricky to do *well* and resiliently, so I would encourage you to keep your function "standard" by sticking with strings only here.

Comment: How do you can your `library` function? As other commented, it would work fine if you pass them as characters. Something like `library('name')`.

Comment: I can't replicate the behavior you observe. When you say "works fine", do you just mean that it doesn't give an error? Are you sure it's loading the package? Have you tried this in a fresh R session? Where are you defining this function? You normally need to pass a character value to use library programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361175/passing-variables-to-the-library-function. Without `base::` you should be stuck in an infinite loop, where the function keeps calling itself.

Comment: @MrFlick, yes, doesn't gives an error. I always call it with double quotes. Worked just fine both in my machine and Kaggle notebook. What puzzles me is that `library()` evaluates variable name instead of it's value. But well, @IceCreamToucan gave the answer already.